# Make the background of a graph different colours in different regions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a straightforward barchart in R using the ggplot2 package.  Rather than the grey default I'd like to divide the background into five regions, each a different (but similarly understated) colour.  How do I do this?

More specifically, I'd like the five coloured regions to run from 0-25, 25-45, 45-65, 65-85 and 85-100 where the colours represent worse-than-bronze, bronze, silver, gold and platinum respectively.  Suggestions for a colour scheme very welcome too.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, off the top of my head is to create a cut variable, facet on the cut and edit the facet grobs using the technique in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750664/how-to-change-the-format-of-an-individual-ggplot2-facet-plot

Comment: I was able to find an example of my suggestion on the ggplot2 mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/fNBQrBPPbPM

Comment: Try adding `geom_rect()` layer(s) with the fill and alpha values that you want. Note that in this application it is convenient to use +/- Inf as limits for the other direction.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers/hints: I'll try and create what I want later today and then accept the appropriate answer (or ask more questions!).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Here's an example to get you started:

```
#Fake data
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))
#Breaks for background rectangles
rects <- data.frame(xstart = seq(0,80,20), xend = seq(20,100,20), col = letters[1:5])


#As Baptiste points out, the order of the geom's matters, so putting your data as last will 
#make sure that it is plotted "on top" of the background rectangles. Updated code, but
#did not update the JPEG...I think you'll get the point.

ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = col), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(data = dat, aes(x,y))
```

[image]

Comment: it's probably better to have the rectangles below the line

Comment: @baptiste - yes, good point. I neglected to think of that in my haste to put an answer together. I incorporated your comments above. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  I have it basically working now.  (Solving my remaining problems is, I think, just a matter of me getting better at understanding making bar charts via ggplot rather than qplot.  The colour/background bit works fine.)

Comment: Hi @Chase a very nice code I maybe can reuse. I have changed rects from x to y and now I'm gonna try with my data that has date and hour on x axis. Is it possible to do? Thanks

Comment: Any idea how to apply this and a `facet_wrap()`?

Comment: With these plots, I like to add `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))` to remove extra space between the rectangles and the axis. I find it more aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to move the line⎯or the bars of the histogram⎯to the foreground, as suggested by [baptiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471093/baptiste) above and fix the background with 
`+ theme(panel.background = element_rect(), panel.grid.major = element_line( colour = "white") )`, unfortunately I could only do it by sending the `geom_bar` twice, hopefully someone can improve the code and make the answer complete.

```
background <- data.frame(lower = seq( 0  , 3  , 1.5 ), 
                         upper = seq( 1.5, 4.5, 1.5 ),
                         col = letters[1:3])
ggplot() + 
    geom_bar( data = mtcars , aes( factor(cyl) ) ) + 
    geom_rect( data = background , 
              mapping = aes( xmin = lower , 
                            xmax = upper ,
                            ymin = 0 ,
                            ymax = 14 ,
                            fill = col ) ,
              alpha = .5 ) + 
    geom_bar(data = mtcars,
             aes(factor(cyl))) +
             theme(panel.background = element_rect(),
                   panel.grid.major = element_line( colour = "white"))
```

Produces this,
[image: geom_bar and geom_rect]

Take a look at [this site](https://kuler.adobe.com/) for colour scheme suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the colour scheme suggestion; this looks promising: 

https://kuler.adobe.com/#themeID/611036

Answer (score 7):

Since you are after vertical (or horizontal) area highlighting, `geom_rect()` might be an overshoot. Consider `geom_ribbon()` instead:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(xmin=3, xmax=4.2), alpha=0.25) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: geom_ribbon]

Comment: Though `geom_ribbon` implicitly takes `ymin` and `ymax` from the data in the panel. If you are potentially going to use a faceted presentation be aware that the ribbon would take different heights in each panel according to the values present.