# How can I have two different scale_fill_manual active in a ggplot command

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

This question follows on from my [earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968975/using-ggplot2-in-r-how-do-i-make-the-background-of-a-graph-different-colours-in) about background colours in ggplot2.

From the answers there, I am now able to use `geom_rect` to give a background to my plot that has five different colours.  On top of that I'd like to plot a barchart that uses two different colours.  I can do each of these tasks separately, but when I try to combine them the `scale_fill_manual` commands clash.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
scores = data.frame(category = 1:4, percentage = c(34,62,41,44), type = c("a","a","a","b"))
rects <- data.frame(ystart = c(0,25,45,65,85), yend = c(25,45,65,85,100), col = letters[1:5])
labels = c("ER", "OP", "PAE", "Overall")
medals = c("navy","goldenrod4","darkgrey","gold","cadetblue1")

ggplot() + 
geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = ystart, ymax = yend, fill=col), alpha = 0.3) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=medals) +
opts(legend.position="none") + 
geom_bar(data=scores, aes(x=category, y=percentage, fill=type), stat="identity") +
#scale_fill_manual(values = c("indianred1", "indianred4")) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4, labels = labels)
```

As written, this makes the two barchart colours the same as the first two background colours.  Removing the "`#`" on the second `scale_fill_manual` command (penultimate line) overrides the background colour commands to make the bars the colours I want but makes the background have just the two colours I want in the `barchart`.

How can I have one `scale_fill_manual` command applying to the `geom_rect` background and the other to the `geom_bar` barchart (or how can I achieve the same effect by other means)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `"a"` and `"b"` in both `rects` and `scores`, so they get mapped to the same color.  Since the rectangles seem to be placeholder values, change them to something distinct that sorts later than anything in `scores`.

```
rects$col <- c("Z1","Z2","Z3","Z4","Z5")
```

Now you can make one `scale_fill_manual` with all (7) colors.

```
ggplot() + 
geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = ystart, 
                            ymax = yend, fill=col), alpha = 0.3) + 
opts(legend.position="none") + 
geom_bar(data=scores, aes(x=category, y=percentage, fill=type), stat="identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("indianred1", "indianred4", medals)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4, labels = labels)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you. 

(I had to switch medals to the start of the values list in scale_fill_manual to get everything to come out like your picture, but doing that worked.)

Answer (score 1):

A more recent option to achieve the same result would be to use the `ggnewscale` package which allows to have multiple scales and legends for the same aesthetic. To this end add `ggnewscale::new_scale_fill()` before (!!) the `geom_bar` to add a second or new fill scale for this geom layer.

Note: As `opts()` will no longer work in more recent versions of `ggplot2` I switched to `theme()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = rects, aes(
    xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
    ymin = ystart, ymax = yend, fill = col
  ), alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = medals) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(
    data = scores,
    aes(x = category, y = percentage, fill = type),
    stat = "identity"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("indianred1", "indianred4")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4, labels = labels) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]