# Change the default colours used by geom_rect in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have used geom_rect to highlight 4 separate sections of my point plot graph, ggplot2 has used a default pink, green, blue and purple to shade in the rectangles, does anyone know of a way to change these default colours?

I didn't bother with a workable example but please let me know if you want one and I can post  in comments

Comment: Not bothering with a workable example is a good way to attract negative votes. Always include one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing ggplot factor colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130497/changing-ggplot-factor-colors)

Comment: @MikeyHarper thanks for the advice, I've  only been using R for about a week or so, after searching the internet for hours for a answer to this question even If I had of come across this question I wouldn't have recognised it as the answer I needed, as I don't know what I'm looking for, hence why I asked my own question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `scale_fill_manual`. An example:

```
library('ggplot2')  #v 0.9.0
library('scales')
(unemp <- qplot(date, unemploy, data=economics, geom="line", 
                 xlab = "", ylab = "No. unemployed (1000s)"))

presidential <- presidential[-(1:3), ]

yrng <- range(economics$unemploy)
xrng <- range(economics$date)
unemp + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = start), data = presidential)
unemp + geom_rect(aes(NULL, NULL, xmin = start, xmax = end, fill = party),
                   ymin = yrng[1], ymax = yrng[2],
                   data = presidential) + 
         scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("blue", "red"), 0.2))
```

More here:
[How can I have two different scale_fill_manual active in a ggplot command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097615/how-can-i-have-two-different-scale-fill-manual-active-in-a-ggplot-command)