# R, ggplot2 - Change background by value and day

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an hourly data frame with three variables: Obs, Model (grouped in "id") and Clouds, i want to compare the observations with the model but i want to color my background according to cloudiness. Clouds is a daily value (it repeats itself every hour of the day).

```
data = pivot_longer(data, cols = 2:3, names_to = 'id', values_to = 'var') %>% drop_na()

g = ggplot(data, aes(x = Time, y = var, group = id)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = Time, xmax = lead(Time), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                color = Clouds), size = 2) +
  geom_line()
```

[Which results in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFtfP.png)

Which is not correct according to the data. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `fill=Clouds`, along with `alpha = 0.5` outside of the `aes()`.

I'm assuming you've already found this, [but I'll leave this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381053/changing-the-background-color-of-a-ggplot-chart-with-a-factor-variable), since it's a similar problem.