# Alternate panel colors of ggplot2 background

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question is fairly straight forward.

[image]
Notice in this screenshot (not sure with what programming language this graph was made) that the background alternates in color between 2 slightly-different shades of grey. I am curious if this is possible within R with ggplot2, to have different colors alternating between the `panel.grid.minor.x` or `panel.grid.minor.y` lines.

I use ggplot quite frequently and have never seen this implemented before, and I don't see how I could do it with any of the `theme()` params, but hopefully I am missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: [Make the background of a graph different colours in different regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968975/make-the-background-of-a-graph-different-colours-in-different-regions)

Comment: @Henrik Henrik's solution seems like the easiest way to go. I don't think you can use the `theme()` controls to accomplish this.

Comment: my stackoverflow searching abilities need work - this is great thank you