# Fill background intervals in ggplotly line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, background, plotly, fill

I'm trying to fill the background of a `ggplot` line graph to indicate day/night periods. The method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968975/make-the-background-of-a-graph-different-colours-in-different-regions) works great, but I want to display them interactively using `ggplotly`, and that becomes a problem because of [this bug](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1559), where ggplotly doesn't like -Inf and Inf used as the y limits for `geom_rect`. Does anyone know of a workaround that will work with ggplotly?

For the sake of readability, I've pasted the example code from the other answer in here:

```r
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))
#Breaks for background rectangles
rects <- data.frame(xstart = seq(0,80,20), xend = seq(20,100,20), col = letters[1:5])

p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = col), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(data = dat, aes(x,y))
p
```

produces this lovely figure:
[image: ggplot line graph with filled background]

However, if you do this:

```r
ggplotly(p)
```

You lose the background fills:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't produce the exact same result where the coloured rectangles reach all the way to the top and bottom but you could use the following: Replace `ymin` and `ymax` `+/- Inf` arguments by `min(dat$y)` and `max(dat$x)` as a workaround. This way the colours will definitely cover all of your `geom_line`, just not reach to the very outside of the plotting area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As juljo mentioned in his comment, the issue is the rectangles' y-range.

**To resolve this issue**:

- **Plot your data first**

  ```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(plotly) 
  dat <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))

  #Breaks for background rectangles
  rects <- data.frame(xstart = seq(0,80,20), xend = seq(20,100,20), col = letters[1:5])

  # Only plot the data
  p <- ggplot() + 
      geom_line(data = dat, aes(x,y))
  ```
- **Get the y-range of the plot**

  ```
      ylims = ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range
  ```
- **Use the y-range to create the rectangles** and add them to the plot

  ```
      p = p + 
          geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = ylims[1], ymax = ylims[2], fill = col), alpha = 0.4)
  ```

#### `p`:

[image]

#### `ggplotly(p)`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had mostly figured it out on my own but I really appreciate the bit about getting the graph's range after the fact.