# How to shade backgrounds of plotly graph in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, graph, plotly

I have a dataframe called blueshade in R, and I would like to **shade** certain background regions a time series interactive plot of this dataframe. I am trying to use **plotly and ggplot** Below is the code I have written so far.

```
months<-c("2007-05-01","2008-01-01","2009-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2011-01-01")
numbers<-c(1,8,50,11,3)
blueshade<-data.frame(months, numbers)
blueshade$months<-as.Date(blueshade$months)

p<-
ggplot(blueshade)+
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=months, y=numbers))

ggplotly(p)
```

If I would like to shade the region between 2007-05-01 and 2008-01-01 **RED**, and shade the region between 2009-01-01 and 2011-01-01 **BLUE**, does anyone know how I would write such code in R? I also want the shading to be somewhat transparent.

Comment: Do you mean shade the background region between those dates, or shade the area between the x-axis and the line?

Comment: Closely related if not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951513/fill-background-intervals-in-ggplotly-line-graph

Comment: The tricky part is `ggplotly` doesn't seem to have the same way to specify `ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf` to get the full displayed range. If a manual solution ok, you could use   `geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end,  ymin = 0, ymax = 55, fill = my_fill), data = data.frame(start = as.Date(c("2007-05-01", "2009-01-01")), end = as.Date(c("2008-01-01", "2011-01-01")), my_fill = I(c("red", "blue"))), alpha = 0.2) +` as your first layer.