# geom_rect to show variation of a categorical variable in the background of line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

1. Below is an example of output vs time.
2. I have used duration to color the line.
3. I also want to include energy level in plot. How can I use rectangle panel (`geom_rect`) in the plot background.

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(time = 1:100,
              output = - time^2 + 5*time,
              duration = c(rep("start", 30), rep("mid", 40), rep("end", 30)),
              energy = c(rep("high", 40), rep("medium", 30), rep("low", 30)))


ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = time,
           y = output,
            color = duration)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the background of a graph different colours in different regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968975/make-the-background-of-a-graph-different-colours-in-different-regions)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: yes sir, the question is similar. I want a background based on energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used data.table to create the helper table energy, I am pretty sure if you prefer another method you can convert it easily.

```
setDT(tbl)
library(data.table)

energy <- tbl[, .(first = first(time), last = last(time)), by  = energy]

ggplot(data = tbl) +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = output, color = duration), size = 2) +
  geom_rect(data = energy, aes(NULL, NULL, xmin = first, xmax = last, fill = energy), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.3)
```

This creates the graph below
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you please  do it with dplyr also

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, but if you wanna the dplyr version, one option is

```
energy= tbl %>% group_by(energy) %>% mutate(first= first(time), last=last(time)) %>% 
  select(energy, first, last) %>% distinct()
```

but I like the data.table version

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to add it as another layer if you override the `y` value. Add transparency by adding `alpha = (% transparent)`.

```
ggplot(data = tbl, aes(x = time, y = output, color = duration)) + 
  geom_line()+ 
  geom_rect(y= anothery, alpha = 0.5)+ 
  theme_bw()
```