# Highlighting time-series regions with geom_rect with fill color according to indicator variable column

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Not sure if this is possible but I'm trying to use geom_rect() to get to something like the plot below. I would like the fill color to change based on an indicator variable.
[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKCtO.png)

The dataframe I'm using looks like this:

| Date | Count | Ind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-10-07 | 373355 | 0 |
| 2019-10-14 | 374307 | 0 |
| 2019-10-21 | 365673 | 0 |
| 2019-10-28 | 354055 | 0 |
| 2019-11-04 | 361637 | 1 |
| 2019-11-11 | 349578 | 1 |
| 2019-11-18 | 372917 | 1 |
| 2019-11-25 | 358007 | 1 |
| 2019-12-02 | 348158 | 1 |
| 2019-12-09 | 337528 | 0 |
| 2019-12-16 | 337553 | 0 |
| 2019-12-23 | 168532 | 0 |
| 2019-12-30 | 223439 | 0 |

Any ideas as to how to do this would be great. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the background of a graph different colours in different regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968975/make-the-background-of-a-graph-different-colours-in-different-regions)

Comment: I was just wondering if there was an easier way than having to specify the xmin and xmax vectors for the geom_rect manually as it is quite a large dataset if that makes sense

Comment: You don't specify them as vectors, they are just the min and max extents of the rectangle. You can just set them as `min(df$Date)` and `max(df$Date)`.