# How do I get a scatterplot with multiple background colors based on the split lines I already know?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, seaborn, visualization

I have a dataframe in which I have x and y values to be plotted using seaborn library. But the cache here is that I need to color the background with multiple colors based on the data points I already have. for example

```
# df - represents the dataframe in which the x and y data are present
split_points = [20,40,60,80,100] # The list of split point, the list can be bigger as well ( keeping it same with the example)
sns.scatterplot(...) # I need help with this to get the below specified graph
```

The snippet of code looks something like above. But I would typically like to get the split of all the points mentioned in the split_points list as different background colors. Hoping to find the method to do the same.

I intend to do something like this.

[image: Image Representing different background colors with different split points]

I have taken the image from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968975/make-the-background-of-a-graph-different-colours-in-different-regions) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `axvspan()` to add the background color for each region, along with `alpha` to control the transparency and `zorder` to move the colored rectangles to the back, so that the lines are on top. For the legend, you can use `label` to provide the text in each case. Below is a working example. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
df=np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=5, size=(100,)) ## data for the line
split_points = [20,40,60,80,100] # The list of split point, the list can be bigger as well ( keeping it same with the example)
split_colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'pink'] ## Colors for each region
sns.lineplot(data=df, color='black', lw=0.75) ## Draw the line plot you want

labels=[*'abcde'] ## Define the labels for the legend

## For each entry, draw the rectangle along with the color, transparency, zorder and label for the legend
for i in range(len(split_points)):
    plt.axvspan(split_points[i]-20, split_points[i], facecolor=split_colors[i], alpha=0.2, zorder=-10, label=labels[i])

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's also a good idea to add something like ```ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left')```