# ggplot2 - using different types for color scales

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to use color scale independently, i.e. for continous and categorical scale.

I have a specific application in mind where I have a simple plot like here

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cylcol = factor(if_else(cyl == 6, "six", "not six"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = drat)) +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

[image]

But I would like also [highlight border, like in the answer of Seth_P, of a specific condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367525/in-ggplot2-how-can-i-change-the-border-of-selected-facets) (I dont't want to use fill background of a facet!). For example

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cylcol = factor(if_else(cyl == 6, "six", "not six"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, show.legend = FALSE,
            ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, aes(col = cylcol), fill = "#00000000") + 
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

[image]

Now I would like to "combine" these two, like that for example:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cylcol = factor(if_else(cyl == 6, "six", "not six"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = drat)) +
  geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, show.legend = FALSE,
            ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, aes(col = cylcol), fill = "#00000000") + 
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

This yields an error `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. This makes on one hand sense, but on the other hand, since both use independent variables I would like to use "different color scales". I could use overlays, like [here, where facet colors are plotted over the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440069/ggplot2-facet-wrap-strip-color-based-on-variable-in-data-set) but I would very much appreciate an easier solution. I'm aware of [specifying fill and color separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011422/ggplot2-using-two-different-color-scales-for-overlayed-plots) - but that is not the goal. I really would like to use color on different scales. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way of having discrete and continuous `colour` scales simultaneously. However, you can work around it by using a `geom_point` shape that is filled by `fill` rather than `colour`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cylcol = factor(if_else(cyl == 6, "six", "not six"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = drat), shape = 21) +
  geom_rect(aes(colour = cylcol), xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
    ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = NA) +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

[image: demo plot]

Here's a second way, which may be a little overcomplicated, but works by splitting the data and effectively doing the faceting manually. The widths need to be adjusted manually according to the y axis label size, the legend size and the plot size.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
lims <- list(x = range(mtcars$mpg), y = range(mtcars$wt))

make_plot <- function(data) {
  cyl <- data$cyl[1]
  if (cyl == 6) {
    rec_col <- "light blue"
  } else {
    rec_col <- "red"
  }
  p <- data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = drat)) +
    geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
              fill = NA, colour = rec_col) +
    xlim(lims$x) + ylim(lims$y) +
    facet_wrap(~ cyl)
  if (cyl != 4) {
    p <- p + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                   axis.text.y = element_blank())
  }
  if (cyl != 8) {
    p <- p + theme(legend.position = "none")
  }
  if (cyl != 6) {
    p <- p + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "white"))
  }
  p
}

mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  map(make_plot) %>%
  grid.arrange(grobs = ., layout_matrix = matrix(1:3, nrow = 1),
               widths = c(0.32, 0.28, 0.4))
```

[image: demo plot 2]

Finally, it's worth noting this was [considered three years ago](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/578) but hadley felt there wasn't enough development bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you. In the post I already write that I'm aware of using fill and color aestetics. However, in my actual plots (not shown here) I use fill already for onther kind of information. Also this workaround would work, it does not work for me.

Comment: Sorry @Drey. I knew you were aware of the separate aesthetics, it's just that often people aren't aware that some of the shapes for `geom_point` use fill rather than colour for their colour.