# Change facet label text and background colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I change the grey facet labels (A and B) into say red background with white text?

```
library(data.table)
A = data.table(x = 1:4, y = 1:4, z = c('A','A','B','B'))
ggplot(A) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + facet_wrap(~z) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can do:

```
ggplot(A) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  facet_wrap(~z) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.background =element_rect(fill="red"))+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(colour = 'white'))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the color of only one label? Lets say I have 5 columns and I want to highlight the center one.

Comment: @Sergio; I haven't played with ggplot for quite a while now, as such I can't give a proper answer, sorry. I could suggest you to look into grob editing (warning : tedious), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750664/how-to-change-the-format-of-an-individual-facet-wrap-panel) might give you some inspiration. There might be some easier solution.

Answer (score 27):

For anyone else looking to change individual facet labels, there's a solution [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2096):

```
g <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
stripr <- which(grepl('strip-r', g$layout$name))
fills <- c("red","green","blue","yellow")
k <- 1
for (i in stripr) {
  j <- which(grepl('rect', g$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]$childrenOrder))
  g$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[j]]$gp$fill <- fills[k]
  k <- k+1
}
grid::grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using the latest version of R and this doesn't work. I get the error `Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index`. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. I'm using R v. 3.6.1, and it looks like some of the plot components' names have changed. To recreate the same plot I changed lines 2 and 3 above to: `striprt <- which( grepl('strip-r', g$layout$name) | grepl('strip-t', g$layout$name) )` and 
`fills <- c("red","green","blue","yellow", "red","green","blue")` (and also changed `stripr` in line 5 to `striprt`.
2. with the recent major update to R, there may be upcoming changes to the ggplot & grid packages that will also alter things. ¯\_(ツ )_/¯

Comment: Is there no way to do this natively in ggplot?

Comment: @vashts85 I get the same. It is because there is nothing in `g$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]$childrenOrder)` that contains `'rect'` for `grepl` to find.

Comment: Just in case someone else needs this, for my newer version I had to change strip-r to strip-1, you might need to look at your particular plot first by first typing g$layout$name this is how I realized that my plot is with -1

Comment: For those experiencing the same problem as @vashts85 and @Matt with updated packages, it seems to stem from `striprt` matching to more than the number of panels. You can simply add a line in the for loop to skip cases that aren't panels: `if(length(j) == 0) next`

Comment: @HermanToothrot - no, it's not possible to do this natively in ggplot. In the link in my answer, Hadley Wickham says "This would require fundamental changes to ggplot2, so is unfortunately not possible." For now you're stuck with ugly work-arounds like this one.

Comment: Anyone have an idea on how to add a legend for the strip colour?