# Change the facet label text based on value in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I'm using `facet_wrap` to look at data from individual replicates at "low power." I want to highlight facet titles by coloring the text of specific values a distinct color. In my actual data, I am using the color element to graph a different variable, so it's unavailable.

A similar thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631806/change-facet-label-text-and-background-colour), but the solution is rather clunky.

As an example, I'll demonstrate with the diamonds dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price))+ 
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap (cut ~ clarity)
```

[image: all labels in default colors]

I'm most interested in diamonds with "Premium" cut, so I want the facet text that says "Premium" to be red, while everything else stays the same.

I tried defining my color and then adding it through the theme element:

```
mycolor <- c("Premium" = "red")

diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price))+ 
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap (cut ~ clarity)+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(mycolor))
```

this produces a warning:

```
Warning: no font could be found for family "red"
Warning: no font could be found for family "red"
Warning: Unable to calculate text width/height (using zero)
```

but still generates a graph:

[image: error with graph]

Comment: Package ggh4x might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010926/20513099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are limited to ggplot2 w/o other newer packages to make life easier, the following brute force approach could be useful:

```
p <- diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price))+ 
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap (cut ~ clarity)

gp <- ggplotGrob(p)

# grob numbers corresponding to facet strips
gp.num <- grep("strip", gp$layout$name)

for(i in gp.num) {
  if(!is.null(gp$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]) &&
     gp$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$label == "Premium") {

    gp$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$gp$col <- "red"

  }
}
rm(i, gp.num)

plot(gp)
```

[image: result]

Do note tweaking this to suit your own use case may require some understanding of the hierarchical relationship among the grobs in `gp`. I've attempted to jot down some points below for reference:

- `gp$grobs[[i]]` = facet strip associated with a single facet panel; it has two child grobs in this case, corresponding to the two rows of facet strip labels since we are using `facet_wrap()` with two variables. If we were using `facet_wrap()` with one variable / `facet_grid()`, it should only have 1 child grob.
- `gp$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]` = grob for the first row of the facet strip. We focus on this since we are interested in varying the text based on `cut`; if we wanted to vary by `clarity`, we'd look at the `..$grobs[[2]]` instead.
- `gp$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[2]]` = title grob for the first row. `..$children[1]]` contains the rectangle background, while `..$children[[2]]` contains the title.
- `gp$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]` = the actual text grob, which exists as a child of the title grob.

Happy exploring :)

Comment: Awesome - thanks! that's definitely brute force. What would you suggest with other packages to make life easier? I'm happy to discover new tools!

Comment: @gromanoibarra ggh4x by teunbrand has been suggested above. In particular, you may want to check out the themed strips [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/ggh4x/vignettes/Facets.html).