# Different colours for facet_grid strip backgrounds

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I would like to change the colours of the strip backgrounds to a predefined order.

This code generates the plot, and changes the strip backgrounds to red:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +
theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="red"))
```

I'd like to do something like the below however, which ideally would specify a different colour for each strip

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +
theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill=c("red","green","blue","yellow")))
```

Which just makes them all red...

This was asked in [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169675/multiple-colors-in-a-facet-strip-background) years ago, the answer was to manipulate grobs. I was hoping that there was a simpler solution in the years since?

Comment: I think the answer is still "grobs". The reason being that facets are more concerned with comparable visualisation of data subset by factors, so their appearance should also be comparable. A better solution might be to colour the points: `geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl))) + scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"))`.

Comment: Maybe worth submitting an issue at GitHub?

Comment: Not an answer, but what I do is put some highly transparent background to each facet to make it distinguishable.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik
Do you just draw on rectangles to the size of the facets? what is the call to get the facet dimensions returned?

Comment: Basically, yes. I use `Inf` for limits.