# ggplot2: use different colors in different facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have what seems to be a very basic problem, but I cannot solve it, as I have barely used ggplots2... I just want that the plot on the left uses the colors in the variable color1 and the plot on the right uses the colors in the variable color2. This is a MWE:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

a.df <- data.frame(
  id=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"), 
  var1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), var2=c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28), 
  var3=c(56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63), 
  color1=c(1,2,"NONE","NONE",1,2,2,1), 
  color2=c(1,"NONE",1,1,2,2,"NONE",2)
)

a.dfm <- melt(a.df, measure.vars=c("var2","var3"))

ggplot(a.dfm, aes(x=value, y=var1, color=color1)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ variable)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a feeling that your data needs to be re-arranged further before the plotting. But to tell if that is the case, can you please provide some more context, and describe your variables a little bit more. Cheers.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267583/programmatically-specifying-colours-in-scale-fill-manual-ggplot-call) covers a lot of the same ground and is worth checking out.

Comment: this is just a very simple example; I have a bigger data frame with a similar structure, with 3 different measuring variables. I want to plot the 1st (in the y axis) versus the 2nd and the 3rd independently (in the x axis). Besides I isolate entries which are the 25% with higher var1 values and higher var2 values, the 25% with lower var1 values and lower var2 values, and the same for var1 vs var3. These are the 2 color scales I want to depict (left=top 25% var1vs2 in red, bottom 25% var1vs2 in blue, rest in black; right=top 25% var1vs3 in red, bottom 25% var1vs3 in blue, rest in black).

Comment: I like simple examples! Thanks for the additional information. There are so many nice ways to map colours in `ggplot` and `stat` functions, so it is good to get a better feeling of how your variables are derived, in order to determine what needs to be calculated in beforehand, and what is more convenient to let `ggplot` take care of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest approach with your data is to create an additional column which has the color defined appropriately based on the value of `variable`. Since there are just two possible values that `variable` can take on, this isn't that hard.

```
a.dfm2 <- transform(a.dfm, 
                    color.use = ifelse(variable=="var2", 
                                       as.character(color1), 
                                       as.character(color2)))

ggplot(a.dfm2, aes(x=value, y=var1, color=color.use)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ variable)
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm not sure I understand the transform() step, but I'll work on it! Thanks!