# Customize background to highlight ranges of data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to set background colors in my ggplot to highlight ranges of data. Particularly, I want to highlight `[-0.1,0.1]` with, say, green,`[-0.25,-0.1)` and `(0.1,0.25]` with orange. In other words, what I need are bars with some alpha-transparency whose y-limits are the plot's y range, and x-limits are set by me.

Ideally, I would want something that would not be sensitive to `coord_cartesian(...)` (as setting `vline(...,size = X)` would). Additionally, it would be nice to have something independent from any data, and based solely on plot coordinates. I tried `geom_segment`, but I could not figure it our how to set a width that would work.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(seq(-1, 1, by = .001))
y <- rnorm(length(x))
df <- as.data.frame(x=x,y=y)

ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(aes(y*abs(x)),alpha=.2,size=5) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-.5,.5),ylim=c(-1,1))
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add the "bars" with `geom_rect()` and setting `ymin` and `ymax` values to `-Inf` and `Inf`. But according to @sc_evens answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521438/geom-rect-and-alpha-does-this-work-with-hard-coded-values) you have to move `data` and `aes()` to `geom_point()` and leave `ggplot()` empty to ensure that `alpha=` of `geom_rect()` works as expected.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=y*abs(x),y=y),alpha=.2,size=5) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=-0.1,xmax=0.1,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),alpha=0.1,fill="green")+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=-0.25,xmax=-0.1,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),alpha=0.1,fill="orange")+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=0.1,xmax=0.25,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),alpha=0.2,fill="orange")+
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-.5,.5),ylim=c(-1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: I just want to check with you: if you set one of the "orange" `alpha` to e.g. 0.1, and the other to 0.9, does it change the appearance of the rectangles? I.e. does `alpha` work the way at least I expected in `geom_rect`? Sorry in advance if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: @Henrik Thank you for pointing to problem with alpha - updated my answer.

Comment: I had a vague feeling I had been struggling with `geom_rect` and `alpha` previously. Just before I got crazy then, I gave up and went for `annotate` instead. Thanks a lot @Didzis Elferts for clarifying this 'issue'!

Comment: I had the same issue before. Thanks for the clarification. I will set this as the answer because Didzis posted before Henrik. Thanks both.

Answer (score 15):

You may try `annotate`, which takes vectors of `xmin` and `xmax` values.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(aes(y*abs(x)), alpha =.2, size = 5) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = c(-0.1, -0.25, 0.1), xmax = c(0.1, -0.1, 0.25),
           ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
           alpha = 0.2, fill = c("green", "orange", "orange")) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-.5,.5),ylim=c(-1,1))
```

[image]