# Why setting transparency (alpha) for background is not working in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm facing some difficulties to set my background plot with some transparency.
simply, whenever I set alpha to any value, same opaque background is returned.
Although there is some posts regarding background highlighting such as

[customize background to highlight ranges of data in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194728/customize-background-to-highlight-ranges-of-data-in-ggplot)

[How to highlight time ranges on a plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733182/how-to-highlight-time-ranges-on-a-plot/4733446#4733446)

[ggplot2: highlight chart area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133846/ggplot2-highlight-chart-area)

But unfortunately, this issue is not discussed here or there.
I would appreciate your comments

Here is some data for demo

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

First , using `geom_rect`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=qsec)) + 
geom_point(color="black",size=8) + 
theme_bw() +
geom_rect(aes(xmin=4,xmax=5,ymin=14,ymax=Inf),alpha=0.9,fill="green")
```

Playing with alpha wont help and ultimately, that is what I got

[image: data from mtcars]

Using `annotate` function , I can not generate it also.

Comment: Your value for `alpha` is too high. See with `alpha = 0.05`.

Comment: The packagename is `ggplot2`, not `ggplot`. And it's generally a bad idea to attach dataftrames.

Comment: Usually, you'd want to switch the order of `geom_point` and `geom_rect`.

Answer (score 1):

Your value for `alpha` is too high.

[image]