# shade regions in R plot

Tags: r, function, plot

I have a plot in R to analyse the functional behaviour of this function :
-2.5*log10(x)  in different regions , the inputs are like this

```
 curve(-2.5*log10(x),0,5,main="Behaviour of magnification function",col=2)
 abline(v=0,col=3)
 abline(v=1,col=4)
 abline(h=0,col=8)
```

Now I would like to shade those regions on the right of the v=1 line and left with two different shades, but can't figure it out how to do. the polygon function  not giving the shade , please help
thanks,
Ayan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `ggplot` solution to the problem, using `annotate`:

First, save the results from curve in `df`:

```
df <- curve(-2.5*log10(x),0,5,main="Behaviour of magnification function",col=2)
```

Then use `geom_vline` to add the vertical lines, and `annotate` to add a `rect` geom to the data for the shaded areas. We use `annotate`, because we do not want to use data from the original data frame as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17584747/3520440).

```
plot <- ggplot(data.frame(df)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, y), size = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept  = 1, color = "blue", size = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color ="grey", size = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "green", size = 1) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 1, xmax = Inf, ymax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = 1, ymax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, fill = "green", alpha = 0.2) + 
  labs(title = "Behaviour of magnification function\n") +
  theme_bw()

plot
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `panel.first` argument to draw in the background.

Define a function to do the drawing:

```
fnShade = function(v,colL,colR) {
  p = par("usr") # limits of the plot 
  rect(p[1],p[3],v,p[4],col=colL,border=NA)
  rect(v,p[3],p[2],p[4],col=colR,border=NA)
  abline(v=v,col=4)
}
```

Then use it

```
curve(-2.5*log10(x),0,5,main="Behaviour of magnification function",col=2,
   panel.first=fnShade(1,5,"grey80"))
```

You can add your other `abline`s into the function if you like.  And it should be easy to extend to draw 4 rectangles - one for each quardant - if desired.

Comment: `rect` is vectorized, so you only need one rect in the function if you define it like this `rect(c(p[1], v), p[3], c(v, p[2]), p[4], col=cols, border=NA)`, have one col argument, `cols = seq.int(v + 1)`, and now you can use a vector of `v` instead of having to define a new function for n-number of panels: call it like `curve(-2.5*log10(x),0,5,main="Behaviour of magnification function",col=2, panel.first = fnShade(c(1,2,3), cols = paste0('grey', 9:6 * 10)))` abline is also vectorized so this would work on that part as well

Comment: Good point @rawr about the vectorization. I think for the single left-right split, the 2 calls to `rect` is probably a bit clearer to illustrate the basic concept, but for flexibility for n panels, I like your approach.  It would have to be modified if we want to handle up-down splits as well as left-right.

Comment: That works thanks a lot.  One more question if you dont mind, now if I want to only shade the region under the plot on the right of the line =1 is that possible ?

Comment: Sure it's possible - this is R :).  But the approach will be different and it might be better as a separate question. (Sorry, no time to work on it today.)

Comment: @AyanMitra you might first search here in Stackoverflow for "shade", specifically "[r] shade" for the `R` tag to see if that gets you started.