# Change background color panel based on year in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, quantmod

I'm plotting a time series for three different years 2013, 2014, 2015.

```
require(quantmod)
require(ggplot2)
getSymbols("AAPL", from='2013-01-1')
aapl.df = data.frame(date=time(AAPL), coredata(AAPL.Close))
ggplot(data=aapl.df, aes(x=date, y=AAPL.Close, group=1))+geom_line()
```

How do I plot the closing price in ggplot such that each year has different background color tiles on the plot?

Comment: Is there a reason for separating the backgrounds by color? Why not color code the line plot itself?

Comment: I could also use:  `p + geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(c(df$date[50],df$date[75],df$date[100]))`    to put vertical lines where I want them but I'd like to figure it out as another option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `geom_rect` for separating the backgrounds.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date("2015-01-01"),
            xmax = as.Date("2015-12-31"),
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = '2015'), alpha = .2)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date("2014-01-01"),
            xmax = as.Date("2014-12-31"),
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = '2014'), alpha = .2)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date("2013-01-01"),
            xmax = as.Date("2013-12-31"),
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,fill = '2013'), alpha = .2)+
  geom_line(data=subset(aapl.df, date < '2016-01-01'),
            aes(x=date, y=AAPL.Close, group=1))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Dark2', name = 'Year')+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

A few posts were used in this solution: [geom_rect and alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521438/geom-rect-and-alpha-does-this-work-with-hard-coded-values) and [using geom_rect to add recessions](http://www.r-bloggers.com/use-geom_rect-to-add-recession-bars-to-your-time-series-plots-rstats-ggplot/).