# Mark range in plot with transparent color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to mark some part of a plot by filling the complete area from some x1 to x2 with (transparent) color in `ggplot2`.
With base R I would do something like:

```
plot(1:100)
polygon(x = c(0, 25, 25, 0), y = c(-1000, -1000, 1000, 1000), col = "#FF000050")
```

[image]

When doing the same with `ggplot2` I'm stuck with the problem that the polygon either does not go to the upper and lower edge of the plot or isn't plotted at all if I limit the y-axis with `ylim`.

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  #ylim(0, 100) +
  geom_polygon(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 25, 25, 0), y = c(-1000, -1000, 1000, 1000)), aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", fill = "red", alpha = 0.1)
```

I don't want to limit the solution to `geom_polygon`, maybe there is a better way to mark this part of the plot. In my real world data plot, I am using `geom_bar` for a stacked barplot, but I don't think the solution depends on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-Inf` and `+Inf` to define the limits of the `polygon` (or better in this case, a `rect`).
`ggplot2` will ignore them for building the plot limits:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100), aes(x = x, y = y)) +     
    geom_polygon(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 25, 25, 0), y = c(-Inf, -Inf, Inf, Inf)), aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", fill = "red", alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 30, xmax = 35, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), color = 'green',  fill = "green", alpha = .1)
```

Note that I moved the data assignment from the `ggplot` call to the `geom_point`. The motive for this is better explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521438/geom-rect-and-alpha-does-this-work-with-hard-coded-values#17584747).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 25, ymin = 0, ymax = 100), fill = "red", alpha = 0.01)+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), expand = c(0, 0))
```