# R - Bar Plot with transparency based on values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataset `myData` which contains x and y values for various `Samples`.  I can create a line plot for a dataset which contains a few Samples with the following pseudocode, and it is a good way to represent this data:

```
myData <- data.frame(x = 290:450, X52241 = c(..., ..., ...), X75123 = c(..., ..., ...))
myData <- myData %>% gather(Sample, y, -x)
ggplot(myData, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(aes(color=Sample))
```

Which generates:

[image: Line plot of absorbance data]

This turns into a [Spaghetti Plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_plot) when I have a lot more Samples added, which makes the information hard to understand, so I want to represent the "hills" of each sample in another way.  Preferably, I would like to represent the data as a series of stacked bars, one for each `myData$Sample`, with transparency inversely related to what is in `myData$y`.  I've tried to represent that data in photoshop (badly) here:

[image: What I would like to make]

Is there a way to do this?  Creating faceted plots using `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()` doesn't give me what I want (far too many Samples).  I would also be open to stacked [ridgeline plots](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/ridgeline.html) using `ggridges`, but I am not understanding how I would be able to convert absolute values to a `stat(density)` value needed to plot those.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a minimal dataset? Generally, you can change the transparency based on values in a variable by adding `alpha = *your column name*` inside the `aes()` section

Comment: Oh wow!  Yes, the answer is through an alpha aesthetic!  I got something to work by running essentially: `ggplot(myData, aes(Sample, x)) + geom_col(aes(alpha=y)) + coord_flip()`.

Comment: For some more info, I was able to get exactly what I needed by switching to `geom_segment()` and applying the aesthetic over alpha.  Key with this approach is to realize that I had to avoid the function from "drawing over" other segments by splitting into individual segments with delta-x = 1.  Here the pseudocode is something like:
`p + geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x-1, y=Sample, yend=Sample, alpha=y), size=8)`.  Worked like a charm.  Even better, I could add `alpha=ifelse(y > num, 1, 0)` to make "hard-edged" rectangles instead of the gradient, with the edges = `num`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [u/Joris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947123/joris) for the helpful suggestion!  Since, I did not find this question elsewhere, I'll go ahead and post the pretty simple solution to my question here for others to find.

Basically, I needed to apply the alpha aesthetic via `aes(alpha=y, ...)`.  In theory, I could apply this over any geom.  I tried `geom_col()`, which worked, but the best solution was to use `geom_segment()`, since all my "bars" were going to be the same length.  Also note that I had to "slice" up the segments in order to avoid the problem of overplotting similar to those found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397603/alpha-in-geom-segment-not-working), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511416/how-do-you-control-the-translucence-of-geom-rect-rectangles/43512827#43512827), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521438/geom-rect-and-alpha-does-this-work-with-hard-coded-values).

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x, Sample)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x-1, y=Sample, yend=Sample, alpha=y), color='blue3', size=14)
```

That gives us the nice gradient:

[image]

Since the max y values are not the same for both lines, if I wanted to "match" the intensity I normalized the data (`myDataNorm`) and could make the same plot.  In my particular case, I kind of preferred bars that did not have a gradient, but which showed a hard edge for the maximum values of y.  Here was one solution:

```
ggplot(myDataNorm, aes(x, Sample)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x-1, y=Sample, y=end=Sample, alpha=ifelse(y>0.9,1,0)) +
  theme(legend.position='none')
```

[image]

Better, but I did not like the faint-colored areas that were left.  The final code is what gave me something that perfectly captured what I was looking for.  I simply moved the `ifelse()` statement to apply to the `x` aesthetic, so the parts of the segment drawn were only those with high enough y values.  Note my data "starts" at x=290 here.  Probably more elegant ways to combine those `x` and `xend` terms, but whatever:

```
ggplot(myDataNorm, aes(x, Sample)) +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x=ifelse(y>0.9,x,290), xend=ifelse(y>0.9,x-1,290),
    y=Sample, yend=Sample), color='blue3', size=14) +
  xlim(290,400)  # needed to show entire scale
```

[image]