# How to add a black overlay semi transparent layer above the background image in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, background-image

I am using **background image** in the plot but the colors of the plot is mixing up with the image so I would like to add an **overlay semitransparent black layer to the background image** so that plot colors can stand out and do not mix with the background..

[image]

I have tried adding `geom_rect()` but that doesn't work well `geom_rect(aes(xmin = min(date), xmax=max(date), ymin = -Inf, ymax=Inf), fill = "black", alpha = 0.3)`

How can I just add a semitransparent overlay layer over the complete background image.

**failed result**

[image]

df

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggpubr)
library(grid)
library(jpeg)

file_url1 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/ts_all_long4.csv"

ts_all_long <- read.csv(url(file_url1))

ts_all_long <- ts_all_long %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))
```

image used: https://github.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/blob/a00c8820363f2163837d24f801f7c5b85167e0aa/coronavirus-4972480_1920.jpg

without `geom_rect()`:

```
ts_all_long %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "Brazil") %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Confirmed_daily)) +
  background_image(readJPEG("Covid 19 images/coronavirus-4972480_1920.jpg")) +
  geom_area(size = 1, col = "#f08080", fill = "#f08080", alpha = 0.5)
```

with `geom_rect()`:

```
ts_all_long %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "Brazil") %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Confirmed_daily)) +
  background_image(readJPEG("Covid 19 images/coronavirus-4972480_1920.jpg")) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = min(date), xmax=max(date), ymin = -Inf, ymax=Inf),
            fill = "black", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_area(size = 1, col = "#f08080", fill = "#f08080", alpha = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17584747/5028841) I tried `annotate()` instead of `geom_rect()`, which does the trick:

```r
ts_all_long %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "Brazil") %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Confirmed_daily)) +
  background_image(readJPEG("/home/johannes/Downloads/coronavirus-4972480_1920.jpg")) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = min(ts_all_long$date), xmax = max(ts_all_long$date), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
            fill = "black", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_area(size = 1, col = "#f08080", fill = "#f08080", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

However, I think it would actually look better to do something like this:

```r
ts_all_long %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "Brazil") %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Confirmed_daily)) +
  background_image(readJPEG("/home/johannes/Downloads/coronavirus-4972480_1920.jpg")) +
  geom_area(size = 1, col = "white", fill = "#f08080", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @JBGruber, really appreciate your help. I was clueless that why `geom_rect()` was not working & was trying `geom_segment()` and never thought could do that with `annotate`. Just one more thing any idea how can I extend this layer from `-Inf` to `Inf` on x axis date scale as the whole background should look same . I tried `annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, 
           ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "black", alpha = 0.3)` but getting an error: `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

Comment: Have also raised this in another SO Post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177555/while-adding-a-semi-transparent-layer-to-background-image-in-r-getting-error-in