# While adding a semi transparent layer to background image in r getting Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, background-image, transparency

I am trying to add a **semitransparent overlay black layer** to **background image** in r plot. It worked by using `annotate` and got the solution from: [How to add a black overlay semi transparent layer above the background image in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67174764/how-to-add-a-black-overlay-semi-transparent-layer-above-the-background-image-in/67175863#67175863)

**Issue:** Semi transparent layer **doesn't extend completely from left to right** over the image of the plot.

If I try use `xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf` then it gives error due to date scale xaxis.

So how do i cover the whole image with the layer ?

df

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggpubr)
library(grid)
library(jpeg)

file_url1 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/ts_all_long4.csv"

ts_all_long <- read.csv(url(file_url1))

ts_all_long <- ts_all_long %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))
```

image used: https://github.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/blob/a00c8820363f2163837d24f801f7c5b85167e0aa/coronavirus-4972480_1920.jpg

```
ts_all_long %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "Brazil") %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Confirmed_daily)) +
  background_image(readJPEG("/home/johannes/Downloads/coronavirus-4972480_1920.jpg")) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = min(ts_all_long$date), xmax = max(ts_all_long$date), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
            fill = "black", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_area(size = 1, col = "#f08080", fill = "#f08080", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

If I extend this from **-Inf to Inf** on xscale: `annotate("rect", xmin = min(ts_all_long$date), xmax = max(ts_all_long$date), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "black", alpha = 0.3) +`

then it gives error **Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only**

Comment: If you replace the infinites with `structure(Inf, class = "Date")` (and -Inf for the xmin), does that work? I've seen a similar issue before: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4308

Comment: yes this worked perfectly. I thought of using `as.Date` earlier on `Inf` but it felt stupid idea. So if you could mention your comment in `Answer` then I will accept your answer to close this post. And really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `scales::date_trans()` transformation doesn't gracefully handle numeric input. I've found a [workaround](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4308#issuecomment-754790218) for this issue by manually constructing infinite dates. Example with a standard dataset below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) +
  geom_line() +
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
           ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "black", alpha = 0.5)
#> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

# Manually constructing infinite dates
ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) +
  geom_line() +
  annotate("rect", 
           xmin = structure(-Inf, class = "Date"), 
           xmax = structure(Inf, class = "Date"),
           ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "black", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

[I've argued](https://github.com/r-lib/scales/issues/298) before that, ideally, the date and time transformations in the scales package should be a little bit more flexible to handle these kind of cases.

Comment: yes totally agree with you and it doesn't feel `scales` to be robust enough when such issues are encountered. Thanks again for helping :))