# Conditionally change ggplot facet background with date axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Using `facet_grid` with `ggplot`, I'm trying to conditionally change the background of some the panels, to highlight ones of interest I've identified. I'm trying to achieve this following the answer from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847559/conditionally-change-panel-background-with-facet-grid).

I understand the idea is to plot a `geom_rect` layer with opacity first to act as the background, but I believe the isolated problem is that when passing parameters to the `rect`, they clash with my actual `x-axis` being a date stamp, leaving the error

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

Below is a minimal example reproducing the problem:

```
dat = read.table(text = "2014-01-25 1  A
2014-02-05 1  A
2014-09-01 1  A
2014-08-26 2  B
2014-12-12 2  C", col.names = c("Date", "Vehicle", "Problem"))

facetcond = data.frame("Vehicle" = 2, "Problem" = "B")

ggplot(dat) +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_rect(data = facetcond, aes(fill = "red"), 
    xmin = as.Date("2012-01-01"), # I've also tried Inf and 
    xmax = as.Date("2016-01-01"), # -Inf here
    ymin = -Inf, 
    ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.Date(Date), fill = Vehicle), binwidth = 14) +
  facet_grid(Problem~Vehicle, margins = "Problem")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've tried a number of different approaches with little success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your error message was that you tried to map an aesthetic to a column that doesn't exist in your data, in this line:

```
geom_rect(data = facetcond, aes(fill = "red"),
```

You are not mapping an aesthetic, but telling `ggplot` to fill the rectangle with red. The line should be:

```
geom_rect(data = facetcond, fill = "red",
```

---

Also, you will also save yourself some trouble by converting the original data frame dates to `as.Date()` prior to plotting. Note that I use `colClasses` to convert the data directly into the class I want, including "Date".

Here is the complete working solution.

```
library(ggplot2)

dat = read.table(text = "2014-01-25 1  A
2014-02-05 1  A
                 2014-09-01 1  A
                 2014-08-26 2  B
                 2014-12-12 2  C", 
                 col.names = c("Date", "Vehicle", "Problem"), 
                 colClasses = c("Date", "integer", "factor"))

facetcond = data.frame("Vehicle" = 2, "Problem" = "B")

ggplot(dat) +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_rect(data = facetcond, fill = "red", 
            xmin = -Inf, # I've also tried Inf and 
            xmax = Inf, # -Inf here
            ymin = -Inf, 
            ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Date, fill = Vehicle), binwidth = 14) +
  scale_x_date() +
  facet_grid(Problem~Vehicle, margins = "Problem")
```

[image]

Comment: So simple! Thank you very much - and also for the `colClasses` tip.

Comment: @Andrie I am not quite sure it is `aes(fill = "red")` _per se_ which generates the error. The main problem seems to be that first providing a _discrete_ fill variable (`aes(fill = "red"`) in `geom_rect`), which sets up the `fill` scale to be discrete, and then provide a _continuous_ fill variable (Vehicle) _after_ the discrete one. E.g. `aes(fill = "red")` in `geom_rect` and `fill = as.factor(Vehicle)` in `geom_bar` works. That said, I fully agree that you should _set_ the color to "red" outside `aes`, and not _map_ it to "red" inside `aes`.