# How to simulate passing an aesthetic to panel background in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I read in this stack overflow question a clever way to simulate setting an aesthetic to panel background using `geom_rect`.

[Conditionally change panel background with facet_grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847559/conditionally-change-panel-background-with-facet-grid)

Unfortunately, it doesn't work if you want to put other colors in the plot. The colors mix and the legend gets polluted. Instead, I would prefer that the color only applies to the background and doesn't get mixed. My other question is: is there an approach that would work in polar coordinates?

For a reproducible example, see the code below:

```
pies <- data_frame(pie = c(rep("hawaiian", 3), rep("pepperoni", 2)), 
                   fraction = c(c(0.3, 0.2, 0.5), c(0.4, 0.6)),
                   ingredient = c("cheese", "pineapple", "ham",
                                  "peperroni", "cheese"),
                   deepdish = c(rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 2)))

p <- pies %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(1),
               y = fraction,
               fill = ingredient),
           width = 0.6,
           stat = "identity",
           position = "fill") +
  facet_wrap(~ pie) +
  geom_rect(mapping = aes(fill = deepdish),
            alpha = 0.1,
            xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
            ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf,
            show.legend = FALSE)

p
p + coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pies <- data_frame(pie = c(rep("hawaiian", 3), rep("pepperoni", 2)), 
                   fraction = c(c(0.3, 0.2, 0.5), c(0.4, 0.6)),
                   ingredient = c("cheese", "pineapple", "ham",
                                  "peperroni", "cheese"),
                   deepdish = c(rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 2)))
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
p <- pies %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(1), y = fraction, fill = ingredient),
           width = 0.6, stat = "identity", position = "fill") +
  facet_wrap(~ pie) + coord_polar(theta = "y")

g <- ggplotGrob(p)
# Set manually the background color for each panel
g$grobs[[2]]$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$gp$fill <- "#88334466"
g$grobs[[3]]$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$gp$fill <- "#44338866"

library(grid)
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
library(egg)
library(grid)

pies <- data.frame(pie = c(rep("hawaiian", 3), rep("pepperoni", 2)), 
                   fraction = c(c(0.3, 0.2, 0.5), c(0.4, 0.6)),
                   ingredient = c("cheese", "pineapple", "ham",
                                  "peperroni", "cheese"))

dummy <- data.frame(x = 0, y = 0, 
                    pie = c("hawaiian","pepperoni"),
                    deepdish = c("green","yellow"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

p <-    ggplot(pies) +
  facet_wrap(~ pie) +
  geom_custom(data= dummy, mapping = aes(x = factor(0),
                            y = y,
                            data = deepdish), 
              grob_fun = function(x) rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=x,col=NA)), inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(1),
               y = fraction,
               fill = ingredient),
           width = 0.6,
           stat = "identity",
           position = "fill") 

p + coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]