# Draw a box around some of the plots when using `facet_wrap` in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I created the following plot with panels using `ggplot()`:

`ggplot(merged.table, aes(x=iter, y=freq,group=var)) + geom_line()+facet_wrap(.~var)`

[image]

I would like to draw a box around some plots whose number is identified in a vector `trueplots`:

`trueplots<-sample(1:25,5)`

I followed the procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336449/highlight-draw-a-box-around-some-of-the-plots-when-using-facet-grid-in-ggplo) and tried

`ggplot(merged.table, mapping=aes(x=iter, y=freq,group=var)) + geom_line()+geom_rect(subset(merged.table, var %in% trueplots),fill = NA, colour = "red", )+facet_wrap(.~var)`

and

`ggplot(merged.table, mapping=aes(x=iter, y=freq,group=var)) + geom_line()+geom_rect(subset(merged.table, var %in% trueplots),fill = NA, colour = "red", xmin= -Inf,xmax = Inf,ymin = -Inf,ymax = Inf)+facet_wrap(.~var)`

but I get the error

```
Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
```

Any hint? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply forgot to put the mapping inside `aes()` and it seems to be in the wrong position in `geom_rect()` argument list (mapping is the first argument, not data).

Example with a standard dataset:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- mtcars
df$facet <- interaction(df$cyl, df$carb, drop = TRUE)

trueplots <- sample(levels(df$facet), 5)

ggplot(df, aes(disp, hp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
            data = ~ subset(., facet %in% trueplots), 
            colour = "black", fill = NA, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ facet)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: God! So simple! It worked! Thank you! :-)