# Panel background color by column in plot matrix, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, facet-grid

I want to make a matrix of plots, with the background color coded to correspond with particular columns (i.e., I want the colors I want, and in a particular sequence).

---

I used info from here [Conditionally change panel background with facet_grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847559/conditionally-change-panel-background-with-facet-grid) to come up with a way to color code background colors, by column, in a matrix of plots in ggplot2, running in RStudio.

But, previously I had been working with some colorblind colors (I'm not colorblind though), and I can't for the life of me get those colors to change to a new set of colors, even when I clear objects from the global environment in RStudio, then reopen the R script in a new RStudio session.  Somehow, by old colors are still remembered.

What I see as output (as a JPG image file) is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I_5GJHOW8VPZShJ4C61Uayo8zrEMPCDZ/ - you will certainly get other colors when running my code.

Two Questions:

1. How can I control those colors/assign particular colors to climate$elevation levels?
2. The approach I've used seems to mask my gridlines within plots - at the bottom of my code you can see I tried to add the gridlines back using 'theme' but it does not work, or is behind the colors of elevation level.  Is there a better way to do this?

---

Here is my code:

```
# install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

#### create Data ####
#####################
temperature<-c(12,43,15,8,7,9,12,15,14,10,34,27,10,12,33,11,15,7,9,12,25,14,9,10,34,37,10,12,33,15,8,7,9,12,15,14,10,34,37,10,12,33,11,15,7,9,12,15,14,9,10,34,37,10,12,33,15,8,7,9,12,15,14,10,34,37,10,12,33,11,15,7,9,12,15,14,9,10,34,37,10,12,15,14,9,36,10,34,37,10)
hour<-c(2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12)
elevation<-c("Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast","Alpine","Montane","Steppe","Valley","Coast")
region<-c("Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America","Europe","N America","S America")
climate<-data.frame(region,elevation,hour,temperature) # create data frame

# Ensures sequence corresponds to sequence of cave zones
climate$elevation <-factor(climate$elevation,
                      levels = c('Alpine','Montane','Steppe','Valley','Coast'),order=TRUE)

# create plot matrix, background colored by elevation
base<-ggplot(data = climate, aes(hour, temperature)) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill = elevation),xmin = -Inf,xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf,ymax = Inf,alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(color = "steelblue", size = 1) +
  geom_point(color="steelblue") +
  labs(title = "Elevation by Region & Time of Day",
       subtitle = "(Temperature)",
       y = "Mean Temperature", x = "Hour of Day") + 
  facet_grid(region ~ elevation)
base

###Plot looks like this to me:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I_5GJHOW8VPZShJ4C61Uayo8zrEMPCDZ/
# I'm certain colors will look different for you!

# Trying to add gridlines (does not work)
base + theme(
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
  panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid',
                                  colour = "white"), 
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I got the same colors as you. The reason is that your `elevation` is an ordered factor. Therefore `ggplot2` by default makes use of the `viridis` color palette.

1. You can set the fill colors using `scale_fill_manual` and e.g. a named vector of colors.
2. There are two options for the grid lines. You can simply add the grid lines manually using `geom_h/vline`. Or you could set the `fill` for the plot and panel background to `NA` and make use of `panel.ontop` which will plot the panel and the grid lines on top of the plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)

cols <- rev(scales::hue_pal()(5))
cols <- setNames(cols, levels(climate$elevation))
cols
#>    Alpine   Montane    Steppe    Valley     Coast 
#> "#E76BF3" "#00B0F6" "#00BF7D" "#A3A500" "#F8766D"

base <- ggplot(data = climate, aes(hour, temperature)) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill = elevation), xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  geom_line(color = "steelblue", size = 1) +
  geom_point(color = "steelblue") +
  labs(
    title = "Elevation by Region & Time of Day",
    subtitle = "(Temperature)",
    y = "Mean Temperature", x = "Hour of Day"
  ) +
  facet_grid(region ~ elevation)

breaks_x <- seq(2.5, 10, 2.5)
breaks_y <- seq(10, 40, 10)

base +
  geom_vline(xintercept = breaks_x, color = "white", size = 0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = breaks_y, color = "white", size = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_x) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks_y)
```

[image]

```r
# Trying to add gridlines (does not work)
base + theme(
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA),
  panel.grid.major = element_line(
    size = 0.5, linetype = "solid",
    colour = "white"
  ),
  panel.ontop = TRUE,
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
)
```

[image]

Comment: ... ggplot by default using viridis? I thought it was scale_color/fill_hue....

Comment: one never stops to learn. And I was actually occasionally surprised why the diamonds data would plot in different colors lol (never questioning it really)

Comment: @tjebo Haha. Me too. First I looked for something strange. Then I restarted my R Session. Then I restarted R. But still viridis ... and then I saw the `order=TRUE` argument in the factor statement.

Comment: Wow, thanks this is super helpful.  Is it possible to get the gridlines behind the plotted data and in front of the background color?  In any case, you got me a lot closer to a professional looking figure.  And I learned things!

Comment: Hi Steve. To the best of my knowledge: Unfortunately no. That's the drawback of `panel.ontop` and the reason why added the second approach using `geom_h/vline`. Best S.