# ggplot facet_wrap different themes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a way to `facet_wrap` different themes in the same `%>%` line, to get something like

[image]

Is there any way to do something similar without having to do

```
fig1 = mtcars %>% filter(am == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) + ggtitle('Theme A')

fig2 = mtcars %>% filter(am == 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
 theme_minimal(base_size = 15) + ggtitle('Theme B')

grid.arrange(fig1,fig2, ncol = 2)
```

Is there a way to display different themes for the `facet` argument in the same line of code?

If not, even just displaying different colour backgrounds for the `facet` argument will be helpful.

Comment: a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847559/conditionally-change-panel-background-with-facet-grid

Answer (score 1):

I would think facets are meant to have the same theme (the only thing changing between facets should only be a column that determines which data goes where and the axes based on certain settings free/fixed/etc.).

As @sam81 suggested, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847559/conditionally-change-panel-background-with-facet-grid) is a good hacked solution based on a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167444/change-options-on-a-per-facet-basis) by hadley